# Load RSA public key Error DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, base64, rsa

I need to encrypt a JSON data for send it in http body with a public RSA key, I load public RSA key file (.der) and it works fine.

The client send me a public RSA key file (.bin). So when I run my program , I get this Error

```
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=109, too big.
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:380) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:386) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:66) ~[na:1.6.0_45
```

My PublicKeyReader class :

```
public class PublicKeyReader {

  public static PublicKey getpublicKey(String filename)
    throws Exception {

      File file = new File(filename);
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
      byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
      dis.readFully(keyBytes);
      dis.close();


    X509EncodedKeySpec spec =
      new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
  }
}
```

And encrypting part in my main class is :

```
    // Encrypt Data with AES
        byte[] keyData = random.generateSeed(16);
        SecretKey skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "AES");
        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        byte[] ivParams = new byte[aes.getBlockSize()];
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivParams);
        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        // Lecture du certificat (cle publique RSA)
        PublicKey clePublique = PublicKeyReader.getpublicKey("./src/main/resources/publique.bin");
        //String clePublique1 = Base64.encodeBase64String(clePublique.getEncoded()).replaceAll(
        //      "(\\r|\\n)", "");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, clePublique);
        byte[] wrappedKey = cipher.wrap(skeySpec);

        // encodedToken : Mot de passe symétrique crypté avec le certificat
        // public (RSA) mis à la disposition de la banque par BAM
        String encodedToken = Base64.encodeBase64String(wrappedKey).replaceAll(
                "(\\r|\\n)", "");
        ;
```

Answer (score 1):

After several research, I found the answer and also the portion of code that I mess.

In my PublicReaderKey class, I Change the way which I read the RSA public Key

with this portion of code :

```
 public static PublicKey getpublicKey(String filename)
    throws Exception {

      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                in));
        try {
            BigInteger m = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            BigInteger e = (BigInteger) oin.readObject();
            KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                return fact.generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(m, e));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Erreur de sérialisation parasite", e);
        } finally {
            oin.close();
            System.out.println("Fermeture de lecture fichier .");
        }

  }
}
```